# mi grafica enciende sus ventiladores pero jamas da video

Tags: hardware

estoy teniendo un problema grandisimo y la verdad no se que mas puedo hacer, tengo una torre de hp prodesk 400 g1 en factor de forma reducido, al conectarle la grafica que tengo esta enciende sus ventiladores pero el pc da video por el vga y jamas detecta la grafica, ya intente cambiar la fuente por una de mas potencia y instalar sus drivers pero nada, porfavor agradeceria la ayuda de alguien estoy sufriendo jaja

Comment: Lo siento, esta es una página de programación, no de hardware. [Aquí](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76731/) puedes ver dónde hacer ese tipo de preguntas dentro de la red stackexchange.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no tiene relación con la temática del sitio (programación).